# Mysql Case - 2 conditions need same update value

Tags: mysql

I am trying to use a mysql case query to update multiple rows in a table. I have some cases which need to update the row with the same value. I was wondering whether it is possible to put all of these into one case or whether I have to create a new 'WHEN' for each?

Below is an example of what I am trying to accomplish but it obviously isn't the correct way to do this because I get an error.

```
UPDATE `groups` SET `status` = CASE `group_id` 
WHEN 32 OR WHEN 33 THEN '1' 
WHEN 31 THEN '2' 
END
```

Is it possible to do something like that?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TRY

```
UPDATE `tablename` SET `status`= IF('group_id=31',2,1)
```

#### EDIT

```
UPDATE tableName SET `status` = IF( group_id IN (31, 32), 2, 1 ) WHERE section_id=1
```

OR

```
UPDATE tableName SET `status` = IF( group_id ANY (31, 32), 2, 1 ) WHERE section_id=1
```

running successfully on my table..what error u facing??

#### other syntax

```
UPDATE `tableName` SET `group_id` = CASE
WHEN group_id IN (31,32) THEN 1
WHEN group_id IN (33,34) THEN 2
END
```

Comment: @diEcho - Would a query like this be possible if say group_id 31 and 32 needed to be status = 1 and group_id 33 and 34 needed to be status = 2?

Comment: [Reference](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if)

Comment: @diEcho - It looks like to use an if statement in my query I would need to do something like this: `UPDATE groups SET row = IF( 'group_id IN (31, 32)', 2, 1 ) WHERE section_id = '1'`

but i cannot get that to work

Comment: @Rob  I UPDATE my answer, btw u can also use `ANY` instead of `IN`

Comment: Thanks for your input. I'm using the other syntax code you provided because it makes more sense to use that with my table structure

Answer (score 3):

I think you want

```
UPDATE groups SET status = CASE
    WHEN group_id = 32 OR group_id = 33 THEN '1'
    WHEN group_id = 31 THEN '2'
    END
```

**Edit** You can use operators like `BETWEEN`. For example

```
UPDATE groups SET status = CASE
    WHEN group_id BETWEEN 32 AND 33 THEN '1'
    WHEN group_id BETWEEN 30 AND 31 THEN '2'
    END
```

Comment: Strange, that syntax works for me. I'm using MySql 5.1 on Ubuntu.